# SQL Assistance: Trying to retrieve rows from two related tables (exclude/ filter-out specific user_id from the results)

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm in need some SQL advice. What is the best way (making use of SQL Joins and/ or Sub-queries) to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance :)

> ```
> users TABLE (user_id = Primary Key)
> ```

```
+---------+----------+------------+
| user_id |   name   |   surname  |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 001     | Tangi    | Amalenge   |
| 002     | John     | Doe        |
| 003     | Sally    | Angula     |
| 004     | Simon    | v Wyk      |
| 005     | Nangula  | Abed       |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

> messages TABLE (message_id = Primary Key;
>       user1 & user2 = Foreign Keys referencing back to users.user_id)

```
+------------+----------+------------+----------------+
| message_id |  user1   |   user2    |  date_created  |
+------------+----------+------------+----------------+
|   101      |   001    |    003     |  2012-05-20    |
|   102      |   002    |    001     |  2012-05-18    |
|   103      |   003    |    005     |  2012-05-18    |
|   104      |   005    |    002     |  2012-05-17    |
|   105      |   001    |    004     |  2012-05-09    |
+------------+----------+------------+----------------+
```

> ```
> I would like to retrieve the names and the id of the message I 
> share with a user. My user_id is 001.
> If I'm user1 in the messages TABLE, then I want to know who user2 is, and if I'm user2,
> I want to know who user1 is, plus the id of the message we share.
> ```

```
Like this:
+----------+------------+
|   name   | message_id |
+----------+------------+
| Sally    | 101        |
| John     | 102        |
| Tangi    | 105        |
+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.name, m.message_id
FROM users u, messages m
WHERE (m.user1 = u.user_id AND m.user2 = "001")
   OR (m.user2 = u.user_id AND m.user1 = 001)
```

Comment: Perfect! @iiro, you are an Expert!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u.name, m1.message_id from users u 
inner join messages m1
On m1.user1 = u.user_id
Inner join Messages m2
On m2.user2=u.user_id
Where m1.user1='001' or m2.user2='001'
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanx for the attempt Sadia, generally, I prefer Subqueries, I understand them way better than Joins...

Comment: NB: You should use joins as much as possible and not to use subqueries becouse you are running the subquery once for every row and the join happens on indexes.